# How to mole SPContext.Current.Site.Url

Tags: unit-testing, moles

Hi I would like to mole my SPContext.Current.Site.Url.
How can I do that?
Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a SharePoint server installed to my workstation, so this may not work:

1. Mole the Microsoft.SharePoint assembly
2. Detour the SPContext class:

```cs
Microsoft.SharePoint.Moles.MSPContext.AllInstances.Current.Site.Url = 
    testContextInstance => "www.tempuri.org/Default.aspx";
```

Comment: I have no Current after MSPContext.AllInstances

Comment: Hmm... I'll get SPS installed on something, and then see what I can find.